# How to enable autoclass feature for a Cloud Storage Bucket on Terraform?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I am using Terraform to create Cloud Storage Buckets and would like to have autoclass feature enabled. I looked through the documentation but I couldn't find an option in Terraform. Is this something that's currently not supported? If so, what is a way I can make it work. I noticed on https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/using-autoclass that I can pass in `fields=autoclass` as a parameter. Is this something I can possibly add to my Terraform config? I tried finding a way to do it but failed to find one

```
curl -X PATCH --data-binary @JSON_FILE_NAME \
-H "Authorization: Bearer OAUTH2_TOKEN" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
"https://storage.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/BUCKET_NAME?fields=autoclass"
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think it's simply not possible today, it's too early

Answer (score 0):

This feature has been added only very recently in version [`4.46.0 (December 12, 2022)`](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-google/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md#4460-december-12-2022) of the Google provider for terraform.

You can use the `autoclass` block like this:

```
resource google_storage_bucket experiments-gcs {
  name          = "your-bucket-name"

  ...

  autoclass {
    enabled = true
  }
}
```

Just make sure you are using an updated version of the Google Provider (`>= 4.46.0`).